# Finding the position of a row element in a 2d ordered array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to build a method in Java where the input is a 2D array of integers and get as a result a 2D array of integers where each element makes reference to a position of an element in a row. Let's me explain that with an example.

Consider as a input for the method a 2D arrays of 7x7 as follow:

```java
int[][] array = new int[][]{
        {280, 103, 351, 226, 451, 563, 507},
        {173, 71, 40, 100, 396, 315, 442},
        {421, 326, 210, 308, 535, 487, 549},
        {87, 165, 0, 19, 213, 405, 281},
        {25, 0, 104, 195, 298, 238, 223},
        {2, 17, 68, 0, 98, 196, 236},
        {356, 225, 454, 408, 567, 681, 604}};
```

I used a method to order this array in increasing order according to the values of each row. The code is the following:

```java
public static int[][] sortRowWise (int m[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < m[i].length - j - 1; k++) {
                if (m[i][k] > m[i][k + 1]) {
                    int t = m[i][k];
                    m[i][k] = m[i][k + 1];
                    m[i][k + 1] = t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // printing the sorted matrix
    int[][] mR = new int[m.length][m[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
            mR[i][j] = m[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mR;
}
```

And the output is:

[image: sorted matrix]

Now I need to build a new 2D array of integer (I will call `newArray` in the following) according with:

1. The minimum value of row 0 in the "not-ordered" array is 103 and is
   associated with column 1 (then, I need to assign a 0 in
   `newArray[0][0]`.
2. Next, the minimum value of row 0 in the "not-ordered" array is 226
   and is associated with column 3 (then, I need to assign a 1 in
   `newArray[0][3]`.
3. And so on for each row...

As said before, the final output of the method must be something like the following 2d array. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: expected result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[][] matrix = {
                {280, 103, 351, 226, 451, 563, 507},
                {173, 71, 40, 100, 396, 315, 442},
                {421, 326, 210, 308, 535, 487, 549},
                {87, 165, 0, 19, 213, 405, 281},
                {25, 0, 104, 195, 298, 238, 223},
                {2, 17, 68, 0, 98, 196, 236},
                {356, 225, 454, 408, 567, 681, 604}};
        print(matrix);
        System.out.println();
        print(transform(matrix));
    }

    public static int[][] transform(int[][] matrix) {
        class Point {
            final int col;
            final int val;

            public Point(int col, int val) {
                this.col = col;
                this.val = val;
            }
        }

        List<Queue<Point>> queues = new ArrayList<>(matrix.length);

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            Queue<Point> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(
                    Comparator.comparingInt(point -> point.val));

            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
                queue.add(new Point(col, matrix[row][col]));

            queues.add(queue);
        }

        int[][] res = new int[matrix.length][];

        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            Queue<Point> queue = queues.get(row);
            int col = 0;
            res[row] = new int[queue.size()];

            while (!queue.isEmpty())
                res[row][col++] = queue.remove().col;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public static void print(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < matrix[row].length; col++) {
                if (col > 0)
                    System.out.print(' ');
                System.out.format("%3d", matrix[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
280 103 351 226 451 563 507
173  71  40 100 396 315 442
421 326 210 308 535 487 549
 87 165   0  19 213 405 281
 25   0 104 195 298 238 223
  2  17  68   0  98 196 236
356 225 454 408 567 681 604
```

```
  1   3   0   2   4   6   5
  2   1   3   0   5   4   6
  2   3   1   0   5   4   6
  2   3   0   1   4   6   5
  1   0   2   3   6   5   4
  3   0   1   2   4   5   6
  1   0   3   2   4   6   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your sorted array and for each element, find which index corresponds in the original array.

```java
int[][] sortedArray = sortRowWise(array);
int[][] result = new int[array.length][array[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
    int current = sortedArray[0][i];
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[0][j] == current) {
            result[0][j] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

Should work for the first line (didn't test it but what matters is the idea)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a binary tree that each node could store the number and its index in original array. Then you traverse for finding the smallest number.

Lets say you implemented the tree that smaller number is on the left side, then you need to traverse as the left node, current node, and the right node.

With something like this:

```java
public static void traverseNode(Node n, List<Integer> a) {
    traverseNode(n.left, a);
    a.append(n.index);
    traverseNode(n.right, a);
}
```

In the end, list a should be the result of a row.

Answer (score 0):

To get a matrix of indices of elements of rows of this matrix in a sorted matrix - you can iterate over the rows of this array and, for each row, iterate over its indices and sort them by the corresponding element values - you get the sorted row of indices. Then iterate over the indices of the sorted row and, for each element, swap its value and index:

```java
int[][] arr1 = {
        {280, 103, 351, 226, 451, 563, 507},
        {173, 71, 40, 100, 396, 315, 442},
        {421, 326, 210, 308, 535, 487, 549},
        {87, 165, 0, 19, 213, 405, 281},
        {25, 0, 104, 195, 298, 238, 223},
        {2, 17, 68, 0, 98, 196, 236},
        {356, 225, 454, 408, 567, 681, 604}};
```

```java
int[][] arr2 = Arrays
        // iterate over the rows of the array
        .stream(arr1)
        // get a sorted array
        // of indices of the row
        .map(row -> IntStream
                // iterate over the
                // indices of the row
                .range(0, row.length)
                .boxed()
                // sort indices by element values in the row
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(j -> row[j]))
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                // return sorted array of indices
                .toArray())
        // get the positions of
        // elements in a sorted row
        .map(row -> {
            int[] arr = new int[row.length];
            IntStream.range(0, row.length).forEach(j -> {
                // swap the row index and
                // the value of the element
                int val = row[j];
                arr[val] = j;
            });
            // return an array of element
            // positions in a sorted array
            return arr;
        }).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr2).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5]
[3, 1, 0, 2, 5, 4, 6]
[3, 2, 0, 1, 5, 4, 6]
[2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 6, 5]
[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Finding indexes of 2d array elements in a sorted 2d array by columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65611365/14940971)</sup>